# Heat map or contour plot for (x,y,z) points in MATLAB, is it possible without mesh function?

Tags: matlab, heatmap, contour

I have been here sitting for hours trying to figure this out with no hope. I hope you can help me. I have (x,y) points in x-y plane each (x,y) point has certain value assigned to it, you can think of it az its z component

I was able to draw these points by a simple matlab function

```
text(position(1),position(2),num2str(RSRP))
```

by doing so I obtained the following figure below

My question is: I would like to see contours or colors as in a heat map according to the tagged value, for example in this figure a certain countour around the point (-400,190) will exist which has value of -117 as tagged will have a certain color while the point at (-300,200) which has the tagged value of -106 will have another contour.

Initial thoughts:

Take it to (x,y,z) plane and then project to 2D. But then I have problem because for each (x,y) I have one value z. I dont have meshgrid function with corresponding mesh. Very confused. Thank you

[image]

I would like something like the one below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would this function help you? 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html

It interpolates data at random x,y locations to a uniform grid.

I riffed on the example they gave and did the following,

```
x = rand([1,50]).*100;
y = rand([1,50]).*100;
%%% z is, say, three gaussians in the xy plane
v = exp(-((x-20).^2+(y-20).^2)./(2*10^2)) + exp(-((x-70).^2+(y-70).^2)./(2*10^2)) + exp(-((x-20).^2+(y-70).^2)./(2*20^2));  
[xq,yq] = meshgrid(1:0.5:100, 1:0.5:100);
vq = griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq);
contourf(xq,yq,vq)
```

This gives the following...

[contour plot from random x,y points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt1ZF.png)

Without being sure what the data is/the goal of this plot I can't comment on how "fair" it is to interpolate the data in this way, but I also made this plot with x,y points which were more dense (vectors of length 200 versus 50 as above) and evenly spaced to show what z is "supposed" to look like.

[contour plot from more dense and evenly spaced points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL6Hs.png)

As we might have guessed, the interpolated contour plot gets some, but not all features. It may be best to use Mohammad's scatter suggestion as this will represent only information you have, but again, this is up to you and certainly depends on the type/purpose of your visualization!

Apologies for the linked pictures/no comments, I'm new here (this is my first answer!) so I can't comment or embed images. Hope this helped regardless!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't fully understand the problem you try to solve, by the way, I will post my voyage idea hope may help.

In the following code, I use `scatter` plot to represent data similar to your figure.

```
clear 
x = random('Normal',1,10,1,100);
y = random('Normal',1,10,1,100);
[t t_idx] = sort(x);
x = x(t_idx);
c = linspace(1,100,length(x));
scatter(x,y,[],c,'*')
```

[image]
If this is not what do you want. Please add dataset sample with related code this will help us to understand your problem better.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry its not so clear. I want something that looks like  figure 2 I just added in my question. The different values on the * in Figure 1 I provided will have different color of contours.

Comment: what about this? `x = 1:10;
y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = rand(10,10);
contourf(X,Y,z,20, 'ShowText','on','LineWidth',0.1)`